# Detect when UITextFiled is being drawn

Tags: ios, oop, uitextfield

I have subclassed `UIViewController` to enable my theming strategy.

That is to say, all of my `UIViewControllers` extend my version called `MyUIViewController` which has an `override` on `viewWillLayoutSubviews`. Therefore, when a page is loaded, I can call my `setupView` method which will properly set my background and other styles and animations for me.

I have done the same thing for my `UITextField`. The problem Im running into however, is that I cannot find a method in the `UITextField` class that gets called every time the view appears.

The basic question is, what is `UITextFields` `viewWillLayoutSubviews` or `viewDidLoad`.

**Some Solutions:**

In the event that there is nothing that gets called I have the following solutions whihc I dont really like.

1. Using the `ViewController`, iterate through all of the subviews that a view controller has and if a given view is type `UITextField`, call a static method in my extension of it to set its style
2. Register my subclass `UITextField` with notification center and when I change the theme, send out a notification.

I have tested both of the methods from the above and they do work, however they are not as nice as having the class itself do what it needs to do when it comes in the view.

To recap, I would like to know if there is a method that I can override in the `UITextField` class that will notify me every time the view comes alive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `func didMoveToSuperview()` is inherited from `UIView` class, just override it anche check if the `superview` value is different from `nil`, this would require to subclass `UItextField`.

> Discussion The default implementation of this method does nothing.
>   Subclasses can override it to perform additional actions whenever the
>   superview changes.

But it seems to me that you are overcomplicating, can you explain a little bit more what are you trying to do with the text field?

**[UPDATE]**
To apply a theme to a whole view controller views, there a lot of thing you can do. The easy way it would be use `NSNotification`s and `viewDidLoad()` of you view controller.
The `viewDidLoad()` method is called when your view controller has loaded its view, that means that if you are not adding views at runtime also your UI will be loaded at that time. Here you can call a method `applyTheme(theme:ThemeObject)` - of course you will need to pass the ThemeObject somehow - where you can apply your subviews customization. If you want to change theme at runtime you can also use `NSNotification` and dispatch one of theme once the user has make its theme selection. All the registered observers can call the `applyTheme(theme:ThemeObject)` method and add their customization.
If you want to abstract the behavior a little you can create a protocol "*Themable*" and add implementations for each kind `UIView` subclass in your protocol extensions.

*I just want also to remember that UIKit provide a similar protocol called [UIApperence](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/), by googling you can find [custom implementations](http://petersteinberger.com/blog/2013/uiappearance-for-custom-views/), it is really a powerful protocol is worth to gave a look.*

Comment: Users can choose the "Theme" that they would like to have in their app. Currently, that means font and background color. This implies that I need to change the font, font color, font size, and border color. I would love to hear if you have another approach to this. This does seem complicated to me too.

Comment: It took me some time to try your answer. Can confirm it works.